# PushSharp error message sending IOS push notification

Tags: c#, ios, push-notification, pushsharp

I am having the same issue. I am not a IOS developer, but I am a c# developer. The iOS developer gave me the provision file to send out Push notification in our running windows service. I tested out PushSharp with just my iPad and it did not work. I received the error message:

> Push Notification Fail: PushSharp.Core.MaxSendAttemptsReachedException: The maximum number of Send attempts to send the notification was reached!

I have tried this locally and on a server, and I am only trying to send 1 push.

Code.

```
var appleCertificate =
File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "sb_push.p12"));
var push = new PushBroker();
/* push.OnNotificationSent += NotificationSent;
push.OnChannelException += ChannelException;
push.OnServiceException += ServiceException;
push.OnNotificationFailed += NotificationFailed;
push.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += DeviceSubscriptionExpired;
push.OnDeviceSubscriptionChanged += DeviceSubscriptionChanged;
push.OnChannelCreated += ChannelCreated;
push.OnChannelDestroyed += ChannelDestroyed;
push.OnNotificationSent += NotificationSent;*/
push.OnNotificationFailed += NotificationFailed;
push.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(appleCertificate, "PASSWORD!"));
push.QueueNotification(new AppleNotification()
.ForDeviceToken(deviceToken)
.WithAlert(message)
.WithSound("default"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also using windows server and I was able to resolved this issue. See "[PushSharp ApplePushService giving a Channel Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703867/pushsharp-applepushservice-giving-a-channel-exception)" and "[Processing multiple Notifications with PushSharp for ios and android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536259/processing-multiple-notifications-with-pushsharp-for-ios-and-android)".  Both got resolved by regenerating my certificate.