# PushSharp ApplePushService giving a Channel Exception

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I was able to send and receive push notification sucessfully for ios device, however now  I am seeig this error:  It appears after it seems to connect but the maximum attempts are reached then it tries 
to connect again and gives this error:  I have used the same credentials before and after seeing these errors it successfully sends the notifications and I get them on my device. It seems to try to connect and then it reaches the maximum attempts and then it tries to connect again and gives this error. If the credentials work once shouldn't it work all the time?

> AMMethod:ServiceException; Channel Exception:
>   PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushService ->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The credentials
>   supplied to the package were not recognized    at
>   System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface
>   SecModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SecureCredential scc)
>   at
>   System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse
>   credUsage, SecureCredential& secureCredential)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]&
>   thumbPrint)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst,
>   Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult)    at
>   PushSharp.Apple.FeedbackService.Run(ApplePushChannelSettings settings,
>   CancellationToken cancelToken)    at
>   PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushService.<>c_*DisplayClass4.<.ctor>b*_1(Object
>   state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by regenerating the certificate.
I installed the new .cer onto the server and exported it into a .p12 to use with the pushsharp code.